# Double Click Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a link_to_remote link - which i want to perform its action on double click...

I am using rails version 2.3.5...

Comment: it is actually about Javascript nor about Rails

Comment: so u mean there is no way to do it in rails...i know the javascript way... but i want to do it in rails - if there is any way... otherwise i have to go for javascript then...

Comment: rails can't do it. rails is server side framework, not client side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listen to double click not click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897558/listen-to-double-click-not-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `dblclick`

http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

```
# Rails 3
<%= link_to "link", :remote => true, :id => "my_link" %>

# Rails 2.x
<%= link_to_remote "my_link", {}, {:id => "my_link"} %>

<script>
  $('#my_link').dblclick(function() {
    alert('Hello world!');
  });
</script>
```

you need just to add jquery support to your app