# Listen to double click not click

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm just wondering why `click` event happening when I `dbclick` an element?

I have this code:([**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/utecey/edit#javascript,html,live))

*HTML*

```
<p id="hello">Hello World</p>
```

*JavaScript*

```
document.getElementById('hello').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  this.style.background = 'red';
}, false);
document.getElementById('hello').addEventListener('dbclick', function(){
  this.style.background = 'yellow';
}, false);
```

It should do different things for click and double click, but it seems when you double click on the `p` it catch `click` event in advance and ignore double click.

I tried `preventDefault` the `click` event too. 
How can I listen to just `dbclick`?

## UPDATE

I had a typo in my code. `dbclick` is wrong. It's `dblclick`. Anyway the problem still exist. When user double clicks the `click` event happens.

This is updated code that prove it:([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/utecey/3/edit))

```
document.getElementById('hello').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  this.style.background = 'red';
  this.innerText = "Hello World clicked";
}, false);
document.getElementById('hello').addEventListener('dblclick', function(){
  this.style.background = 'green';
}, false);
```

Comment: You mean `dblclick`, presumably.

Comment: This question made because of a typo. I wish I could delete it!

Comment: Why?! There are some other important points raised in the answers. Please don't ignore the advice given just because you made a typo. The question "How can I listen to _just_ `dblclick`" is _not_ solved by fixing your typo.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal you are right! I updated question.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal do you think `stopPropagation` would help here?

Comment: Nope. (Doing _anything_ in the `click` event can't change what happens depending on whether `dblclick` goes on to happen _later_, short of invoking a magical time-travel function.) My answer is comprehensive. Sorry.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`dblclick` is not magical: though the second rapid `click` fires the `dblclick` event, the first `click` has already triggered its own event handler.

You should pretty much never set both a `click` and a `dblclick` event on a DOM element; when you do, you'll need fancy tricks with timers to mitigate the issue.

In this specific scenario, you'll also need to fix your typo (`s/dbclick/dblclick/`) to get the event to fire at all.

<sup>Also note that [`dblclick` is not actually part of the DOM specification at all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.ondblclick) (not present in [DOM Level 2 1.6.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mouseevents)). For this reason it's known as a "[DOM Level 0](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/glossary.html#dt-DOM-Level-0)" feature.</sup>

Comment: I've had no problems using both with some simple cases, e.g., single-click means the user has selected some item in a list, so perhaps display more info about that item and/or enable an associated button, while double-click means auto-click the associated button.

Comment: @nnnnnn: In that scenario, perhaps double-selection was transparent to the user. The same would probably be true for the OP's specific scenario, but it's no general rule.

Comment: +1, and going to the JSBIN and fixing the `dbclick` to be `dblclick` it does just what I expect: turns red from the click event then yellow from the dblclick event.

Answer (score 13):

Change `'dbclick'` to `'dblclick'`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `dblclick` instead of `dbclick`.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the revised question (How to mutually exclusively handle click and dblclick) you have to delay the click event until dblclick is no longer possible. This gives a slight lag (e.g., 500ms) to click handling but otherwise there is no way for the DOM to predict whether a second click will be arriving.

An example script is in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11057483/43217

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (using the d3 library, but d could also be a dictionary object):

```
function log(s){try{console.log(s)}catch(e){}} // for debugging

var click_d = null

function click(d){
    log("click")
    click_d = d
    setTimeout(click_action, 200)
}

function click_action(){
    log("click_action")
    if(click_d == null){
        log("aborted")
        return
    }
    d = click_d

    // do things with d
}

function doubleclick(d){
    log("dblclick")
    click_d = null

    // do things with d
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I would suspect you are working on slow computer. On a slow computer double click could be interpreted as two single click with significant time in between. You can experiment with mouse setting and change the double click setting. That should troubleshoot the problem. If you are computer *is* really fast and has no lag issue, your problem could be somewhere else. It is very unlikely that double click could be taken as single click as code bug (the one you posted). Problem could be elsewhere if not slowness of the computer.

Comment: -1: Execution time isn't particularly relevant, other than that it exists; you'll still get at least the initial `click` event. A downvote here _may_ be a little harsh, but I think it can probably be taken as read that the OP knows what a double click feels like on his computer.